# Setting model value conditional in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a model with the following field

- published (boolean)
- published_at (datetime)

when updating the model, i want to set **published_at** to **Time.now** when **published** is set **true**!

any advice how i can achieve this? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your model you need to put this

```
before_save :set_published_at

def set_published_at
    @published_at = Time.now if @published == true
end
```